# cost of printer ink per page?

Tags: printer, ink

I want to buy a new printer for home use (mainly for school work). I guess these requirements mean ink injection printer. I'm wondering if there's a reference that shows the cost of the ink for a single page, or, some way to create a common base. E.g., if one cartridge model suffices for 1000 pages while another is for 500 pages, then the latter should cost half to be equal to the first.

Comment: For what kind of printing? Which printers are you actually comparing? How much do you print? Your question really lacks some basic information.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite difficult to know the exact cost of a page since it really depends on what you are printing.
Are you printing plain text? Are you printing a document with a lot of colorful images, fancy charts, etc?
As you can see, the reference you ask for should take in consideration all kinds of scenario's.

There is a big different between ink and laser printers though, where laser printers tend to be very much less expensive in the long term with a few thousand prints per toner at least. However, the printer itself is much more expensive compared to a ink printer.

Considering you're talking about 1000 pages in your question, I recommend forgetting about ink printers and go with a laser printer. I bet you could buy a few laser printers (including toner) for the money it will cost you on inkt-cartridges.

Answer (score 0):

In my career, I once actually sold computer hardware, including printers, and I learned the following.

When it comes to inkjet printers, the cheaper the printer is, the more expensive will the ink be to replace that.

It comes down to: How often will you print with it? If you print say 1 page every week, you should go for a cheaper printer. Replacing the ink will be more expensive, but it will not outweight the costs of a new printer.

If you print a lot, say 20 pages a day, an expensive printer is likely going to be a good choice, because the ink will be cheaper then in comparison.

Also a note, if you are going to print only on occasion, say once every month or longer, do not get an inkjet printer, but instead get a laser printer. Inkjet printers can dry out, while laser printers cannot, and nowadays laserprinters are not that expensive anymore either. For the little printing you're going to do, you would otherwise have the problem of ink drying out and be constantly buying ink.

Do note that when the statistics for a printer says you can print 10000 prints with it, they refer to printing mostly black and white on a draft quality. If you aim for a very high quality, in colour, you will print lots and lots of ink, and it may go down to 500 pages before the ink is all out. The same applies to laser printers too. Note that with a laserprinter, you will also have a fuser that will have to be replaced at some point. The quality setting will affect the lifespan of the fuser too, but if you print little, it will take a year or more before you have to replace anything.

Also, note that when you buy a printer, the ink/toner that comes with it will only be 1/5th full. This is always the case, so do not compare how much you can print from that ink cartridge / toner, and order a replacement one as well. Ink will not dry out until it has been opened for the first time.

Comment: I have an borther ink injection printer and I never had issues with ink drying

Comment: @IttayD Its not the ink that will dry out, it are the ink printer heads. To avoid, print at least once a month. If it didn't dry out for you, then you probably print at least once a month.